# Guardar en un Array o un Json los datos de un formulario al clickear botón 'Registrar'

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Soy totalmente nuevo en `Xaml` y en `C#` (*Por eso no coloco código de avance*), estoy tratando de hacer una App en `UWP`, y básicamente lo que quiero, es que al momento de dar **click** sobre el botón *Registrar*, en el `evento click` generado se cree un `array` o un `Json` con los datos que se ingresaron en cada uno de los campos del formulario.

Si alguien me explica cómo es el proceso y cómo puedo lograrlo, se lo agradecería. (Adjunto Imagen Formulario)

Es decir, quiero algo así:

```
var objetoJSON = {
 "identificacion":"valorIdentif",
 "nombre":"valorNombre",
 "apellido":"valorApellido",
 etc....
 etc....
};
```

**(Me disculpan, si la sintaxis no es de C#, pues hasta ahora estoy aprendiendo el lenguaje, pero prácticamente eso es lo que quiero)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para el caso de que quieras generar un JSON

1 - Para el siguiente ejemplo representare tu formulario primero como un objeto.

En visual studio creo la clase `Formulario.cs` que contiene las siguientes clases.

```
public class Formulario
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public Latitute latitude { get; set; }
    public Longitude longitude { get; set; }
}

public class Latitute
{
    public float value { get; set; }
    public string orientation { get; set; }
}

public class Longitude
{
    public float value { get; set; }
    public string orientation { get; set; }
}
```

La acción de presionar el botón registrar debera hacer lo siguiente:

1) crear variables con sus tipos de datos correspondientes
2) *setear* los datos.

(pondré los datos "en duro", pero acá debes asignar los valores con los campos de tu formulario, ahí debes cambiar los tipos de datos a los tuyos según corresponda):

```
        var latitude = new Latitute();
        latitude.value = 123456;
        latitude.orientation = "S";

        var longitude = new Longitude();
        longitude.value = 123456;
        longitude.orientation = "N";

        var formulario = new Formulario();
        formulario.id = 123456789;
        formulario.name = "patricio";
        formulario.lastName = "vega";
        formulario.location = "santiago";
        formulario.phone = "12345678";
        formulario.email = "el@email.com";
        formulario.latitude = latitude;
        formulario.longitude = longitude;
```

Una vez seteados los datos, podemos transformar nuestra variable formulario de tipo Formulario a JSON utilizando  [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) , lo puedes instalar en tu proyecto vía NuGet.

agregamos la referencia

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

y luego dentro de la acción del boton registrar

```
 string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(formulario);
```

Debería quedar algo como esto:

```
                 var latitude = new Latitute();
            latitude.value = 123456;
            latitude.orientation = "S";

            var longitude = new Longitude();
            longitude.value = 123456;
            longitude.orientation = "N";

            var formulario = new Formulario();
            formulario.id = 123456789;
            formulario.name = "patricio";
            formulario.lastName = "vega";
            formulario.location = "santiago";
            formulario.phone = "12345678";
            formulario.email = "el@email.com";
            formulario.latitude = latitude;
            formulario.longitude = longitude;

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(formulario);
```

si inspeccionamos la variable `json` podremos ver tus datos con formato `JSON`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta @patovega , seguiré tus sugerencias y te haré saber cómo me fue.

Comment: @FernandoChamorro ok, me avisas para ver si la es la respuesta correcta.
para crear un arrray es el mismo tema, pero obviamente usando array en vez de Newtonsoft.json.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu explicación, funcionó correctamente. Fue perfecta tu explicación. *Que pena no haber respondido antes*.

Una última dudita, ahora que se almacena el `Json` al momento de clickear el botón, cómo hago para que **por cada click** en '*Registrar*', se cree un Json general cuyos ítems sean `ObjetosSerialize` diferentes?

De nuevo, muchas gracias por entender mi desconocimiento en C# y .Net y por darme esa excelente explicación.

Comment: @FernandoChamorro debe asociar al objeto a los elementos de tu formulario, asi, por cada click tomara los valores que tenga el formulario. a eso te refieres?

Comment: Bueno, pues ya logré hacerlo así como tú me explicaste y funcionó perfecto, es decir, ya tengo el `Json` con cada uno de los campos del `Frm`, a lo que me refiero, es que quiero crear un array o un objeto general donde se guarden o acumulen los Json que genere cada vez que cliquée sobre el `Btn Registrar`, y cada ítem de ese `Json` general, sea un nuevo registro.

Comment: @FernandoChamorro ¿ guardar los datos en una base de datos ?

Comment: No @patovega; No lo estoy haciendo con BD, en reemplazo a la Bd, quisiera hacerlos con Json o en su defecto arrays, pero que este Json contenga todos los nuevos registros que se creraron al oprimir el botón registrar. En resumen sería: Un ítem nuevo del Json por cada nuevo registro que se crea al clickear el botón.

Comment: @FernandoChamorro ah ok, deberías crear un objeto que contenga una lista de Formularios. ejemplo: var lista = New List<Formulario>(); y vas a agregando a la lista cada uno de los formularios creados. una cosa asi se me ocurre.

Comment: Gracias @patovega, lo intentaré.